# Only the first task in a dag gets executed in airflow when schedule_interval set to @once

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I was testing airflow 1.10, using the following dag:

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='something',
start_date=datetime(2019,1,2).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')),
schedule_interval='@once',
...)
```

I then have several bash operators:

```
o1 = BashOperator(bash_command="echo 0", dag=dag, task_id='o1')
o2 = BashOperator(bash_command="echo 0", dag=dag, task_id='o2')
o3 = BashOperator(bash_command="echo 0", dag=dag, task_id='o3')
o1 >> o2 >> o3
```

Airflow parses and displays the dag with no problem. However, when I trigger the dag, only the first task runs and gets marked as green. The dag then just remains in the 'running' state while all other tasks are marked in white meaning they are not picked up by the scheduler. I then receive an email saying:

```
Executor reports task instance finished (success) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok..I think I figured it out, the problem is with the timezone-aware start_date. The problem went away once I removed `replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))`